# remove SVG tag from html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove an HTML svg `<tspan>` tag which has coordinate dy=\"14\" from the following string

```
      "<text x=\"264\" style=\"color:#606060;cursor:default;font-
    size:11px;fill:#606060;width:140px;text-overflow:clip;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" 
    transform=\"translate(0,0)\" y=\"389\" opacity=\"1\"><tspan>xyz</tspan>
<tspan dy=\"14\" x=\"264\">abc</tspan>"
```

is there a way I can use the JavaScript match() and replace() the whole tag when it identifies the string ' dy=\"14\" '

In this case the whole tspan tag which contains abc should be removed.

Comment: Don't try to use regex to parse XML, this is a solved problem already. Use search.

Comment: did you understand the question?? @Nit

Comment: Yes I did, this is a duplicate of countless similar questions, use the site search.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, kindly flag it

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can parse a string of HTML into a useable jQuery object.  For instance, you could try something like this:

```
var rawDocument = "<text x=\"264\" style=\"color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:140px;text-overflow:clip;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0,0)\" y=\"389\" opacity=\"1\"><tspan>xyz</tspan><tspan dy=\"14\" x=\"264\">abc</tspan>";

var document = $(rawDocument);

document.find("tspan[dy=14]").remove()

console.log(document);
```

Why would this be preferred over some JavaScript methods like `String.match` or `String.replace`? Well, both those either take a Regex or string input.  Since it'd be a bit difficult to parse that with a string using one of those functions, you'd have to resort to Regex.  But Regex wasn't designed to parse, and on top of that JavaScript's Regex engine isn't the best.  Since you have jQuery at your disposal, I'd take advantage of that.